# Select distinct record with multiple time related

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database that contains staff awarding history so in future we can calculate how many awards are awarded to a specific staff. I have another column that contains information about how many times a staff arrived to work without a smart dress, which has date associated. I would like to calculate the numbers of awards awarded to each staff, numbers to time a staff fail to wear a company's uniform. Currently my database looks:

```
  ID   fName   sName     awards    smart    date  
  1    jack    Mack        1        0       2014-05-06
  2    Jimmy   Jack        0        1       2014-04-06
  3    Jack    Mack        1        1       2014-05-04
  4    Jack    Mack        1        0       2014-02-03
  5    Jimmy   Jack        0        1       2014-05-01
```

Based on above table I have created another table, that should have only single entry for a record e.g.

```
  ID   fName   sName     awards    smart    date  
  1    jack    Mack        3        1       2014-05-06
  2    Jimmy   Jack        0        2       2014-04-06
```

But in here the problem is the date, Jack is been given 3 awards in different days. In future if I need to select records between two dates then how would I go about and do this because in my table I have removed repeated record and what SQL does is, it takes the top date and use it. 
If I count number of 1's in my first table (where records are being repeated), I get wrong data my query is:

```
select ID, fName, sName, awards, smart, date, 
    count(case awards when 1 then 1 else null end) 
from tablename 
group by ID, fName, sName, awards, smart, date
```

The reason for receiving wrong data is once again due to time? Is there any way to get around this problem?

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: And why do you need a date in your output if there's multiple dates?

Comment: @Szymon I am using Microsoft server management 2008, I need date because in my web form i am displaying date too plus in some of my query i am getting records betwen two dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you group records (e.g. to get totals, etc.), it makes sense to return only those columns that you can use for grouping. This means only those columns that are the basis of your group for calculations. In your case, only `fName` and `sName` are used for grouping (as you're grouping for unique staff).

(Side note: you should have some sort of unique identifier for your staff in this query as names are not necessarily unique).

Therefore, you should only include those columns in `group by`. You can use `sum` function to get the number of `awards` and `smart` as they have values of 0 and 1.

```
select fName, sName, 
    sum(convert(int, awards)) as awards,
    sum(convert(int, smart)) as smart,
    max([date]) as maxdate
from tablename 
group by fName, sName
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da83d/1) (I added only relevant columns).

Comment: using sum I get an error: `Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator.` I am using server 2008

Comment: @User911 Didn't know the column type. I updated my answer, try it now.

Comment: It works but it doesnt sum the awards it only shows 1 or 0 next to a record. Return type for award column is bit. plus how do i bring in date. I would like to display date in a web page

Comment: It works for me in that way but soon as I bring in date it stops working! why is that? I need date so that I can display numbers of awards between two dates.

Comment: You need to add those dates to your `where` clause. But that's a topic for a different question...

Comment: What I meant I want it to display date as part of a column.

Comment: @User911 Well, you cannot do that unless you take the minimum or maximum date from all grouped rows.

Comment: thats what I need, how would I display date as part of my select statement. I dont mind having a maximum date selected for a specific record. I try doing this - `select fName, sName,max(date), sum(convert(int......... group by fName, sName, date` but it selects only the first date and display either 1 or 0 under awards or smart column. It dosent add them

Comment: @User911 I updated the query and sql fiddle to show it works. You cannot put date into group by.

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(id), fName, sName, 
       sum(awards) as awards, 
       sum(smart) as smart, min(date) as date
from the_table
group by fName,   sName
```

UPDATE Try to use `sum(NULLIF(smart,0))`